# Set a Tab Bar Item Badge after the tab bar has loaded in Swift 4

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

The goal is to set a badge on a single tab bar item, but only when some other logic elsewhere in the app is called. Right now I have a class MainNavigationController extending UITabBarController, this is where the tab bar is configured. In the MainNavigationController I also have a public function as seen below

```
func setBadge() {
    print("setting Badge")

    self.tabBar.items?[1].badgeValue = "1"

}
```

When I call this function from else where in the app using MainNavigationController().setBadge() the print statement is run but the tabBar item at index 1 is not updated with a badge. How can I get this badge icon to show?

EDIT
Solution based on @Robert Dresler comment. The problem was that I wasn't accessing the proper instance of the MainNavigationController...

```
 let rootView = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? BaseViewController
 let tabBarView = rootView?.centralViewController as? MainNavigationController
 tabBarView!.setBadge()
```

Comment: Thanks, MainNavigationController is the TabBarController. This MainNavigationController is called in the BaseViewController, which is the root view controller. In the root view the centralViewController variable is the MainNavigationController. So I was actually able to get this working based off that, Updated in the edit. Is this the best way to handle situations like this? Thanks for pointing out the problem here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller whose method you’re calling isn't the same instance as controller which is presented so it doesn't have connected any controllers so it has no tab bar items. You have to get reference for the exact controller which is being presented.

Comment: I'm calling setBadges() from a controller outside the embedded view controllers, so this doesn't work in my specific case, good to know tho. The edit I made in the OP works to get the instance of the MainNavigationController - thanks again

Comment: @DaveFaliskie ok, I'll keep just explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
if let tabbar = self.tabBarController as? MainNavigationController {
        tabbar.setBadge()
}
```